# How to return an instance of Inherited class from parent abstract class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I'd like to solve such problem. I have some abstract class and a concrete class with setters that return the instance of that class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

  private Integer id;
  
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public BaseEntity setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }
}
```

next abstract:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class NamedEntity extends BaseEntity {
  private String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public NamedEntity setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }
}
```

and finally a concrete class:

```
@Entity
public class Person extends NamedEntity {
  private String address;

  public String getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
  }
}
```

I'd like to use this kind of builder but in current setup it's not working due to different return types of parent setters

```
  public Person build() {
    Person person = new Person()
        .setId(1);          //return BaseEntity instead of Person
        .setName("name")    //returns NamedEntity instead of Person
        .setAddress("foo"); //return Person!
    return person;
  }
```

of course ther's a workaround with overriden setters but.... can it be done other way using generics?

```
  @Override
  public Person setId(Integer id) {
    super.setId(id);
    return this;
  }
  
  @Override
  public Person setName(String name) {
    super.setName(name);
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: Where is your build class located?  Is it a member of `BaseEntity`?  Builders don't have to be fluent.  It looks like you're just constructing a `Person` then setting its attributes.  What's wrong with `person.setId(1);`, `person.setName("name");`, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same trick as enums (`Enum`), a generic type parameter for the child class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity<E>> implements Serializable {

  private Integer id;
  
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  protected final E getThis() {
      return this;
  }

  public E setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    return getThis();
  }
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class NamedEntity<E extends NamedEntity<E>> extends BaseEntity<E> {
  private String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public E setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return getThis();
  }
}
```

For child classes of Person you need not continue with this pattern.

```
@Entity
public class Person extends NamedEntity<Person> {
  private String address;

  public String getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public Person setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Now you can do_

```
Person einstein = new Person()
  .setId(76)
  .setName("Albert")
  .setAddress("Princeton, New Jersey");
```

The alternative is a *Builder* pattern, however it has the same inheritance problem, and you might end up with *.Builder classes inheriting from parent Builder classes.

I would even say it is not worth this boiler plate code, just for a fluent API (chained calls). The criteria API for instance does hardly need using created objects, and the passed values for the setters must come from some code too.

Also setters implies the classes are *mutable*. It would be much nicer if most fields were immutable. With entity classes unrealistic, but setters are an ugly initialisation. When possible use constructors/builders without setters.

Comment: This does not compile in Java SE 11. Have you tried it?

Comment: @newacct **You are absolutely right.** The result of the setters should have been **`BaseEntity<E>`'' and ''`NamedEntity<E>`** and even then `Person` probably will not work. I have no java compiler at hand. The OP has answered his own question - now I understand why.

Comment: One pattern that is used if you want to return `E` from those methods is you can define an abstract method `getThis()` in the base class that returns `E`, and then in the setter methods, you can `return getThis();`. Then each implementing class, where `E` is a specific type, would implement `getThis()` by returning `this` (or whatever instance of `E` they want; as long as it's an `E`, it's type safe).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the sugestions
I know the builder pattern, but in this particular case is the same workaround as overriding the methods `setId` and `setName`
The point here is:
it is possible that `setId` method will return the instance of child class the method is called from

let's say I'd like to put a complex object to my builder (why not?):

```
public class Person extends NamedEntity {
    private String address;

... getters/setters
    
    public Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }
    
    public final static class Builder {
        private final Person person;
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private String address;
        
        private Builder() { 
            this.person = new Person(); 
        }
    
        public Builder withId(Long id) {
            person.setId(id);
            return this;
        }
..... other setters
        
        public Builder withDto(PersonDTO dto) {
            person
            .setId(dto.getId())
            .setName(dto.getName())
            .setAddress(dto.getAddress()
        }
        
        public Person build() {
            return person;
        }
    }
}
```

as you may guess the `person.setId` returns instance of BaseEntity

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) by introducing a nested class `Builder` with a set of self-returning methods (i.e. returning an instance of `Builder`) which can be chained in a fluent way.

Method `Builder.build()` should return an instance of `Person`.

***Note*** that you setters of your entities can be `void`.

That's how implementation might look like:

```
public class Person extends NamedEntity {
    private String address;
    
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    
    public static class Builder {
        private Person person;

        public Builder() {
            this.person = new Person();
        }
        
        public Builder name(String name) {
            person.setName(name);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder address(String address) {
            person.setAddress(address);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder id(Integer id) {
            person.setId(id);
            return this;
        }

        public Person build() {
            return person;
        }
    }
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
Person person = new Person.Builder()
    .name("Alice")
    .address("Wonderland")
    .id(1)
    .build();
```

***Note:***

- There could be multiple ways to obtain an instance of `Builder`. You can introduce in the `Person` class a static method `builder()` returning a new `Builder`, or static methods like `withName(String)`, `withId(Integer)` might also be handy (*for inspiration have a look at* [`User`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html#withUsername(java.lang.String)) *class from Spring Security*).
- When dialing with immutable objects, `Builder` class should have all the field of the target class duplicated instead of keeping the reference to the target object. And in such case, method `build()` would be responsible for constructing an instance of the target type.

Comment: hope this gets upvoted/accepted. it's a pity nowadays with new questioners...